# In django 1.1, how do I find a form field's max_length attribute

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that looks like this:

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In my django template, I want to reference the fact that the length is 100.

I tried
    {{ form.text.max_length }}
to no avail.

On a related note, how do I reference this value in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an instance of a `Form` you can access the fields (and their attributes) like this:

```
form.fields['text'].max_length
```

In Django template syntax, this would be:

```
{{ form.fields.text.max_length }}
```

Comment: thanks. I need to figure out when to use form.[fieldname] and form.fields.[fieldname]. I'm a little closer now.